# Does Azure DevOps Services REST API 7.0 still support the workItemRefs parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get all the data for completed pull requests from one of my project's repositories and store it in a json file.

> However, I am running into a problem where the `workItemsRef` property is always `null` when I run my GET request.

I'm using the following ADO documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

My application is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Console Application, and I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json package for serializing and de-serializing JSON objects.

Here is the url that I use to execute the request:
`string url = "https://dev.azure.com/{0}/{1}/_apis/git/repositories/{2}/pullrequests?api-version=7.0&searchCriteria.status=completed`
where `{0}` is my Organization Name, `{1}` is my Project Name, and `{2}` is my Repository Id.

I tried hitting the endpoint in my browser to see what the result will be and sure enough there was no `workItemRefs` parameter. My issue does not appear to be JSON serialization/de-serialization related. I'm expecting to see an array that contains any work items that are linked to the pull request with their `id` and `url` fields as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#resourceref)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I can reproduce this problem.

As a workaround, you can use the following [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to retrieve a list of work items associated with a pull request.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/workitems?api-version=7.1-preview.1
```